# Change between images using Fade In/Out animations

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change between images using fade in/out and I am having a difficult time.

This is what I have for the code

```
public void fade(View view)
    {
        ImageView loveLive = findViewById(R.id.lovelive);
        ImageView rikoCheer = findViewById(R.id.rikoCheer);

        loveLive.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        rikoCheer.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

    }

    public void fade2(View view)
    {
        ImageView rikoCheer = findViewById(R.id.rikoCheer);
        ImageView loveLive = findViewById(R.id.lovelive);

        rikoCheer.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        loveLive.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);


    }
```

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lovelive"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="fade"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lovelive"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-69dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rikoCheer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:onClick="fade"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rikocheer"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

so my goal for this is to fade in and fade out between images

Answer (score 0):

What's going wrong exactly? If nothing's showing up it might be that you don't have any layout constraints set up for your images (the `tools:` stuff only affects the layout editor, like fake data for testing, it doesn't apply when you run the app)

There's something called a [TransitionDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Transition) you might want to use, you'd basically create a new Drawable XML file and put this in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lovelive" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rikocheer" />
</transition>
```

and then you can just use that in an ImageView or whatever.

In your code you'd go

```
myImage = (TransitionDrawable) findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.thatImageView).getDrawable()
```

and then you can call `myImage.startTransition(duration)` to go from image 1 to image 2, or `myImage.reverseTransition(duration)` to go back to the first image. You can switch immediately with `resetTransition()` for image 1 or `startTransition(0)` to go straight to image 2

You also might want to use `setCrossfadeEnabled()` on the `TransitionDrawable` - when it's `false` the first image is always opaque, so the second is drawn on top of it like an overlay. If it's set to `true` you get one fading out while the other fades in - depends what you want!